# Ensure all vector components are greater than some number

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a `vec2` containing x and y coordinates.  I need to ensure that they are both greater than 16.  My first attempt:

```
if (gl_FragCoord.xy > 16.0) {
  // do something..
}
```

It fails to compile with a "no matching operand" error.

It works if I compare each dimension of the vector separately.

```
if ((gl_FragCoord.x > 16.0) && (gl_FragCoord.y > 16.0))
  // do something..
}
```

Is there any better way to check all the elements of the vector at once?

Comment: you probably want to look at [lessthan](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/lessThan.xhtml) and [all](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/all.xhtml).

Comment: what you could do is add a check that their product is higher than 256 before checking each coordinate against 16. Please note that this is only necessary, and not sufficient; adding this condition will improve your performance if you know for a fact that there enough coordinate pairs that do *not* pass this condition

Comment: Cool optimization! @AlexBarac

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a [function for component-wise comparison](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/greaterThan.xhtml) that produces a boolean vector and then [another one to check components of a boolean vector](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/all.xhtml):

```
if (all(greaterThan(gl_FragColor.xy, vec2(16.0))) {
    /* ... */
}
```